# What are the contexts where Bash doesn't perform word splitting and globbing?

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, glob

Bash doesn't perform word splitting in globbing in these cases:

## LHS or RHS of an assignment, except for indexed arrays

```
var=$value                                # simple variable
declare -A hash
key="key with a space"
hash[$key]=$value                         # index of an associative array

arr=$(echo "1 2 3")                       # word splitting does happen here
```

## Inside `[[ ]]`

```
var="one two"
if [[ $var = *" "* ]]; then ...           # check if var has a space in it
if [[ $(echo "one two") = $var ]]; then   # use the output of command substitution to compare with var
```

## Inside `(( ))`

```
((sum = $(echo "99 + 1")))                  # assigns 100 to sum
```

## In herestring

```
cat <<< *                                 # gives '*' as the output
```

## In a case statement

```
var="hello world"
case $var in
  "hello world") echo "matches!";;
  ...
esac
```

Is there a definite list of cases where Bash does or doesn't perform word splitting and globbing?

Comment: There's a whole section in the Bash manual on [Shell Expansions](3.5 Shell Expansions) which goes through the details of the sequence in which expansions occur, and the various sections describing the various constructs you list — and the ones you don't...`for`, `$((…))`, etc.

Comment: Cross-posted on [U&L StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441690/what-are-the-contexts-where-bash-doesnt-perform-word-splitting-and-globbing), and has an exhaustive answer there.